# Mail Not Sending In Contact Form 7 Submission

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working with contact form 7 but mail is not sending to my gmail id,
can anybody tell me what should i do to send email in inbox not in spam.

Comment: using Contact Form 7 (Version 5.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

The mails sended via the contact form 7 plugin should have a sender with the domain of your wordpress site. If your site url is "https://www.mypage.com", you can use "noreply@mypage.com" or anything else, but make sure to use the same domain. So the sender really is your domain, otherwise gmail will mark it as spam because it "fakes" the domain it is coming from.

If gmail still puts it in the spam folder, please make sure you are using the right syntax for from header:

```
Yourname Ormessage <noreply@mypage.com>
```

Your first name and second name, the mail address inside of brackets.

Make sure you have a reply-to set with a real existing mail-adress you are reading:

```
Reply-To: info@mypage.com
```

What does the subject of your e-mail look like? This could also be a reason why gmail marks it as spam. Don't use a subject too long and don't use "spam like" words or sentences.

---

You checked everything but gmail still puts it in your spam folder? Maybe you should use a smtp plugin to send your emails reliably: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

If nothing works for you, maybe you have marked it as spam inside your gmail by mistake? You can mark it as no-spam again. But this will only affect your mail account. Maybe you try to send the email to someone elses mail address, so you can check if the issue is with your personal account.

Hope this helps.